# Call js function when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, keypress

I want to call a js function when a button is pressed. After reading [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html) and [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/keypress/index.html), I did something like this in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/38/). However, when I press the button, nothing happens! What am I missing?

js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ref1').keypress(function() {
        alert('Handler for .keypress() called.');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think, it's very easy. It should be click instead of keypress.

Comment: So what is keypress for ? Well, for keyboard keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `keypress` event on `<a>` element, use `click`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/h7gxpqn0/39/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ref1').click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" id="ref1" title="Refresh page if you did shit" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-refresh ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all"
    role="button">
      <p>Refresh page (helpful in case of mistake)</p>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```